# How do I read stdout/stderr output of a child process correctly?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, process

I have written a program `a.exe` which launches another program I wrote, `b.exe`, using the [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425(VS.85).aspx) function. The caller creates two pipes and passes the writing ends of both pipes to the CreateProcess as the stdout/stderr handles to use for the child process. This is virtually the same as the [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499(VS.85).aspx) sample on the MSDN does.

Since it doesn't seem to be able to use one synchronization call which waits for the process to exit *or* data on either stdout or stderr to be available (the [WaitForMultipleObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687025(VS.85).aspx) function doesn't work on pipes), the caller has two threads running which both perform (blocking) [ReadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365467(VS.85).aspx) calls on the reading ends of the stdout/stderr pipes; here's the exact code of the 'read thread procedure' which is used for stdout/stderr (I didn't write this code myself, I assume some colleague did):

```
DWORD __stdcall ReadDataProc( void *handle )
{
    char buf[ 1024 ];
    DWORD nread;
    while ( ReadFile( (HANDLE)handle, buf, sizeof( buf ), &nread, NULL ) &&
            GetLastError() != ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE ) {
        if ( nread > 0 ) {
            fwrite( buf, nread, 1, stdout );
        }
    }
    fflush( stdout );
    return 0;
}
```

`a.exe` then uses a simple [WaitForSingleObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687032(VS.85).aspx) call to wait until `b.exe` terminates. Once that call returns, the two reading threads terminate (because the pipes are broken) and the reading ends of both pipes are closed using [CloseHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724211(VS.85).aspx).

Now, the problem I hit is this: `b.exe` *might* (depending on user input) launch external processes which live longer than `b.exe` itself, daemon processes basically. What happens in that case is that the writing ends of the stdout/stderr pipes are inherited to that daemon process, so the pipe is never broken. This means that the WaitForSingleObject call in `a.exe` returns (because `b.exe` finished) but the CloseHandle call on either of the pipes blocks because both reading threads are still sitting in their (blocking!) ReadFile call.

How can I solve this without terminating both reading threads with brute force ([TerminateThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686717(VS.85).aspx)) after `b.exe` returned? If possible, I'd like to avoid any solutions which involve polling of the pipes and/or the process, too.

**UPDATE:** Here's what I tried so far:

1. Not having `b.exe` inherit `a.exe`; this doesn't work. the MSDN specifically says that the handles passed to CreateProcess must be inheritable.
2. Clearing the inheritable flag on stdout/stderr inside `b.exe`: doesn't seem to have any effect (it would have surprised me if it did).
3. Having the `ReadDataProc` procedure (which reads on both pipes) consider whether `b.exe` is actually running in addition to checking for `ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE`. This didn't work of course (but I only realized afterwards) because the thread is blocked in the ReadFile call.

Comment: Maybe try CancelSynchronousIO ?

Comment: @adf88: according to the MSDN page on `WaitForMultipleObjects`, it can way on all kinds of things - but not pipes. My experiments seem confirm this: the read end of the pipe is always signalled, even when there is no data available. The CancelSynchronousIO() function looks nice, but it's not an option for me since it's only available on Windows Vista and newer.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593175/breaking-readfile-blocking-named-pipe-windows-api

Comment: @adf88: The question you reference looks similiar, but it's not a duplicate of this question. I'm facing the same symptom, but I'm asking for solutions in a much wider solution space than in that other question.

Comment: It should be sufficient for `b.exe`  to pass `FALSE` to the `bInheritHandles` argument of CreateProcess().

Comment: @HarryJohnston: It's been almost four years since I posted this question, but what you suggest sounds like what I wrote as item 1. in the 'What I tried so far' paragraph.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: I interpreted that to mean that you tried getting `a.exe` to pass `FALSE` to the `bInheritHandles` argument when launching `b.exe`.  You can't do that, as you pointed out, because `b.exe` needs the standard handles.  The daemon processes don't, though, so `b.exe` is free to launch them without inheritance.

Comment: Related: [launch an exe/process with stdin stdout and stderr?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485923/launch-an-exe-process-with-stdin-stdout-and-stderr/39648986). Also, see [tiny-process-library](https://github.com/eidheim/tiny-process-library) which is very convenient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is seems that on Windows versions prior to Windows Vista (where you can use the [CancelSynchronousIO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363794(VS.85).aspx) function, there is no way around terminating the reading threads using [TerminateThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686717(VS.85).aspx).

A suitable alternative ([suggested by adf88](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164234/how-do-i-read-stdout-stderr-output-of-a-child-process-correctly/3170626#3170626)) might be to use asynchronous [ReadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365467(VS.85).aspx) calls, but that's not possible in my case (too many changes to the existing code required).

Answer (score 3):

1. Use named pipe and asynchronous ReadFile
   or
2. Parse the output read from the pipe looking for the end (it may be too complicated in your case).

Comment: +1: Parsing the pipe output, looking for an 'end of process' marker, is a creative idea. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> What happens in that case is that the
>   writing ends of the stdout/stderr
>   pipes are inherited to that daemon
>   process, so the pipe is never broken.

Daemons **should** close their inherited file descriptors.

Comment: +1: This is an interesting point of view; for what it's worth, the daemon program which `b.exe` launches is the program of a customer. However, before blaming him, I'd like to have some more arguments to support this claim. Do you happen to have a link to some explanation, or maybe you can extend your reply a bit?

Comment: Becoming a daemon means making some operations ("daemonizing") and closing inherited file descriptors is one of them (on UNIX they are often redirected from/to `/dev/null` rather than closed). I believe this is taught in every book on UNIX system programming (yup, I remember you are concerned with windows, but the notion of daemon initially came from UNIX). (Splitting comment due to the length restriction)

Comment: For online reference you can use Wikipedia article https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Daemon_(Unix)#Types_of_daemons and references it contains.
You can google a lot of HOWTOs on writing daemons, like this: http://www.cs.aau.dk/~adavid/teaching/MTP-05/exercises/10/Linux-Daemon_Writting.pdf (section 4.6 "Closing Standard File Descriptors")

Comment: By the way, if you don't want to mess with your customer, you can close file descriptors by yourself. On UNIX this would look like:
fork (create a copy of the current process);
in the child process:
close file descriptors (or redirect them);
exec "b.exe" (execute the code of b.exe in the current (child) process). Since windows lack fork/exec calls, there is probably some equivalent of this sequence of operations.

Comment: Windows has a SetHandleInformation((HANDLE)theSockFD, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0) call that you can use to make sure a particular socket does not get inherited by child processes that get spawned.  I think the author of b.exe would be the one that would need to call that, though.

Comment: The general rule for Windows is that you shouldn't mess with the standard handles (Windows doesn't have file descriptors!) if you aren't going to use them.  (The main reason is that, depending on how the process was launched, they might not be valid.)

Answer (score 0):

set some global flag (bool exit_flag) and write something to pipe in a.exe