# C++ Pipe ReadFile function set timeout in Windows XP

Tags: winapi, timeout

Is there a way to perform `ReadFile` with timeout in Windows XP?

If not, is there a way to break the pipe from other thread?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Breaking ReadFile() blocking - Named Pipe (Windows API)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593175/breaking-readfile-blocking-named-pipe-windows-api)

Answer (score 1):

Set up an asynchronous ReadFile using [Overlapped I/O](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365603%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  You can then use [CancelIOEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363792%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to cancel the read at any time.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about a named pipe, the usual way is to do an overlapped read, and specify a timeout when you call `WaitForSingleObject` (or `WaitForMultipleObjects`). When/if the timeout expires, the wait will return `WAIT_TIMEOUT` instead of `WAIT_OBJECT_0`.

Comment: @Erik: Specify `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` when you create the named pipe, and pass an `OVERLAPPED` struct when you call `ReadFile` (or any number of other possibilities such as `ReadFileEx` -- Microsoft has done several iterations of overlapped I/O).