# Win32 API: ReadFile timeout

Tags: winapi, timeout

How can I set timeout for ReadFile and WriteFile operations,

When using interprocess pipes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ Pipe ReadFile function set timeout in Windows XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7380385/c-pipe-readfile-function-set-timeout-in-windows-xp)

Answer (score 5):

You have to use the asynchronous version of the function, by specifying `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`.

When a timeout is reached you can call `CancelIO` with the file handle.

Comment: Was afraid of that. Thank you.

Comment: Nothing to be afraid of, it's really not hard to use. You don't need another thread or anything: start the unblocking call, `WaitForSingleObject` for 2 seconds, and `CancelIO` if it didn't go through.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi there is also `GetOverlappedResultEx` with timeout, seems like it's a bit more convenient and you will also get the number of bytes read.