# Implementing a ReadFile with a timeout inducing too much CPU ussage

Tags: c#, readfile

I use kernel32.dll ReadFile to read the HID output of a connected device. I wanted to create a timeout because this call is a blocking method and if it hangs for any reason the main loop in my application also hangs.

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static internal extern bool ReadFile(IntPtr hFile, [Out] byte[] lpBuffer, uint nNumberOfBytesToRead, out uint lpNumberOfBytesRead, IntPtr lpOverlapped);

    public static HidLibrary.HidDeviceData.ReadStatus FastReadWithTimeout(this HidLibrary.HidDevice device, byte[] inputBuffer, int timeout)
    {
        return FastReadWithTimeoutWorker(device, inputBuffer, timeout).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    private static async Task<HidLibrary.HidDeviceData.ReadStatus> FastReadWithTimeoutWorker(HidLibrary.HidDevice device, byte[] inputBuffer, int timeout)
    {
        var task = Task.Run(async () => {
            try
            {
                uint bytesRead;
                if (NativeMethods.ReadFile(device.Handle, inputBuffer, (uint)inputBuffer.Length, out bytesRead, IntPtr.Zero))
                {
                    return HidLibrary.HidDeviceData.ReadStatus.Success;
                }
                else
                {
                    return HidLibrary.HidDeviceData.ReadStatus.NoDataRead;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return HidLibrary.HidDeviceData.ReadStatus.ReadError;
            }
        });
        if (await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(timeout)) == task)
        {
            return task.Result;
        }
        else
        {
            device.CancelIO();
            return HidLibrary.HidDeviceData.ReadStatus.WaitTimedOut;
        }
    }
```

The issue is my current method of doing this causing more CPU overhead than I can allow. Is there something wrong with the way I am doing this or is there a better way to implement a timeout in a native method?

I also just discovered SetCommTimeouts(), but am having trouble finding a working example of it, documentation is spotty.

Comment: Hard to guess when you don't quantify anything.  Not the way I would do it, I would create a FileStream from the device.Handle and use its BeginRead() method.

Comment: @HansPassant well its hard to quantify to begin with, but lets ballpark it and say at a rate of 200 reads/sec (yes it does need to be that high) I see about 4x the cpu usage of this method over just calling ReadFile.

I am completely unfamiliar with using streams to handle HID device IO

Comment: @HansPassant A quick look says that reading a memory stream just calls ReadFile, so by trimming it down I am likely omitting some overhead with my pinvoke. Not to mention I have seen too many HID libs that check the device status before each read which induces a ton of overhead.

Comment: I am convinced that SetCommTimeouts() is what I need to be using, cannot find enough info on it to get it working though, my attempts return error 1, which I cannot find a reference for. I will likely close this and open a new ques regarding that.

Comment: No, that is for serial ports, not HID devices.

Comment: @HansPassant the limited references I have found so far indicate that ReadFile respects SetCommTimeouts settings

Comment: @HansPassant "When reading from a communications device, the behavior of ReadFile is determined by the current communication time-out as set and retrieved by using the SetCommTimeouts and GetCommTimeouts functions." - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile

Comment: A "communications device" so far as Windows is concerned is a device attached to either a Serial port or a Virtual Serial Port. USB is more like a LAN connection. A Virtual Serial Port may be on top of the USB layer however the `DCB` and the `SetCommTimeouts()` settings apply to the Virtual Serial Port layer, not the USB transport layer the virtual port layer uses. My testing with timeouts with `ReadFile()` with a USB path to a USB device required using OVERLAPPED I/O because the `SetCommTimeouts()` applies only to Serial Port devices and not USB devices.

Comment: See as well this post and answers about using `OVERLAPPED` with `CreateFile()` for opening the connection to the USB device using the USB path then starting a `ReadFile()` followed by using one of the Wait function such as `WaitForMultipleObjects()` then `GetOverlappedResult()` to check the I/O and doing a `CancelIo()` if needed because of a time out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7380385/c-pipe-readfile-function-set-timeout-in-windows-xp