# Non blocking alternative to Readfile() from fileapi.h ? C#

Tags: c#, io, blocking

Currently reading data packages from a HID_DEVICE. In a windows desktop application c#.
When the device is on, everything is perfect. Packages are readed and handled as pretended.
The problem comes when the device is connected but not turned on.
The application gets stuck in the readfile () because it has nothing to read.

So my question is:

Is there any way to see if the Readfile() has something to read, before calling it?
or failing that, some non-blocking alternative to Readfile()

I have tried adding a timeout, but this seems to mess up the rest of the application.
Took the idea from here:
[Implementing a ReadFile with a timeout inducing too much CPU ussage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53362883/implementing-a-readfile-with-a-timeout-inducing-too-much-cpu-ussage)

Readfile() function documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile

Edit_0: Runing into the same problem with filestream as sugested in comments.
Can i somehow check if the connected hid device is turned on/off?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And why you are using ReadFile ? you can `new FileStream(handle, ...)` and then use async read methods from FileStream class

Comment: Ty for the answer Selvin. 
Im using Readfile() because the app came with the readfile function already implemented. But im cheking filestream(), but probably wont be able to change Readfiles. As they already work, kind of

Comment: Except by your descriptions, Readfile isn't working (for what you need). You need to be reading asynchronously if you don't want the UI to hang on those IO operations, you could try placing the ReadFile calls on a background thread, or you could use a more direct async implemented method, for instance as provided by FileStream.

Comment: So, can i use fileStream to read from a HID_device?

Comment: See as well this post and answers about using `OVERLAPPED` with `CreateFile()` for opening the connection to the USB device using the USB path then starting a `ReadFile()` followed by using one of the Wait function such as `WaitForMultipleObjects()` then `GetOverlappedResult()` to check the I/O and doing a `CancelIo()` if needed because of a time out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7380385/c-pipe-readfile-function-set-timeout-in-windows-xp